# Only one application instance with FireMonkey

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, instance, firemonkey

With **FireMonkey** and a multi-platform application (**Windows** + Mac **OS X**), how to have **only one instance** of an application running at the same time?

**If a previous instance is already running, how to set it as the desktop foreground window**?

- I can check if a file is locked:

  - **not locked**: I lock it and run normally
  - **locked**    : find the previous version (on windows, I know how to.. but on mac ?) and set it as the foreground window
- I can check how many times the same process is launched (ditto, on windows, ok, but how to do it on Mac OS X)
- ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081218/ideal-way-to-single-instance-apps-on-the-mac

Comment: Also, I hope you don't do that file based thing on Windows. Use a named mutex.

Comment: I got some issue with mutex since Vista... but maybe I mix different issues in my memory (like mutex and services, ...) ;o)

Comment: BTW... I understand that this should not happen on Mac... but as explained in other questions, if you duplicate the application, this could occured... which bother me ;o)

Comment: All the same, what you need on all platforms is a mutex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both for Windows and OSX you can get the list of running applications and check if yours is in the list before you close with a message. In OSX you can get the list with lauchedApplications method of NSWorkspace, and in Windows you can use the toolhelp32 library for same purpose. 
Here are the related codes from TPlatformExtensions class which I have blogged in my website.

For OSX:

```
uses Macapi.AppKit, Macapi.Foundation;

class procedure TPlatformExtensionsMac.GetRunningApplications(
  Applist: TStringlist);
var
  fWorkSpace:NSWorkSpace;
  list:NSArray;
  i: Integer;
  lItem:NSDictionary;
  key,value: NSString;
begin
  fWorkSpace := TNsWorkspace.Wrap(TNsWorkSpace.OCClass.sharedWorkspace);
  list := fWorkspace.launchedApplications;
  if (List <> nil) and (List.count > 0) then
  begin
    for i := 0 to list.count-1 do
    begin
      lItem := TNSDictionary.Wrap(List.objectAtIndex(i));
      key := NSSTR(String(PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode('NSApplicationBundleIdentifier'))));
      // You can also use NSApplicationPath or NSApplicationName
      value := TNSString.Wrap(lItem.valueForKey(key));
      Applist.Add(String(value.UTF8String));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

For Windows:

```
uses Winapi.TlHelp32, Winapi.Windows;

class procedure TPlatformExtensionsWin.GetRunningApplications(
  Applist: TStringlist);
var
 PE: TProcessEntry32;
 Snap: THandle;
 fName: String;
begin
  pe.dwsize:=sizeof(PE);
  Snap:= CreateToolHelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if Snap <> 0 then
  begin
    if Process32First(Snap, PE) then
    begin
     fName := String(PE.szExeFile);
     Applist.Add(fName);
     while Process32Next(Snap, PE) do
     begin
       fName := String(PE.szExeFile);
       Applist.Add(fName);
     end;
    end;
    CloseHandle(Snap);
  end;
end;
```

If you need further information about the subject you can read my [article](http://delphiscience.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/getting-list-of-running-applications-in-firemonkey-for-windows-and-osx/) on the subject.